# How to get the last build date in Hudson

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson

How can I get the **last build date** in maven context from Hudson? I need to pass that date back to **Maven** to generate a**changelog** report.Is there a better way to achieve that?

I am using Hudson 2.2.1 and Maven 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a while ago. I thought that I should share this here as I originally asked this question. There is a REST call you can make in Hudson, which gives you the last successful build. A mixture of the rest call and xpath, you will get the last build date in the YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss format.

**Maven Antrun task:**

```
<loadresource property="build_start_date">
     <url url="${JOB_URL}/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=/*/id/text()"/>
</loadresource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it would help to understand what you are exactly trying to achieve, from what I understand,

Could you not maintain a properties file with a timestamp of the last build? The time stamp will be updated with each built.

You could read the last build time from this properties file and use it in whatever maven plugin you are using.

You may choose to check-in the properties file back to SCM to ensure that last build date is reflected to be same on all the individual machines. If you only need this on Hudson machine, you are good without putting this file into SCM.

Answer (score 0):

Use the environment variable **BUILD_ID** to get the timestamp of the latest build. 
The timestamp you get will be in `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss` format. Use [ZenTimestamp](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) plugin to format it to the required format.

or

Install [Hudson Groovy builder](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) plugin and execute the groovy script to get the last build information

```
myjob = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("job_name") 
lastbuild = myitem.getLastBuild() 
println lastbuild.getTime()
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible as the BUILD_ID would be the current build id and not the last one. I am looking for the last build date.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use the **maven-changes** plugin and pas the **changelog.xml** generated by hudson as the `xmlpath` property?

Comment: I don't have much of an idea about maven.